# Changing Body Background Color in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using top tab navigation in my react native app. Now, I want to change the gray background color inside it. But I am not familiar with react-native styling. How may I do that?

Here is the background in my app.

[image]

And here is the code for the navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the color you want in screenOptions :

```
screenOptions={{
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
    }
  }}
```

Comment: I have added the color in the screenOptions as you said. However, the color didn't change. Here is a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1qjqu20

Comment: Well you can symply add a <View style={{backgroundColor: "white"}} /> in all your screens Tab, it'll works the same

Comment: Only the component background changes when I do that. Please check the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1qju79t But I want the entire screen color to be changed. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You need to add "flex: 1" in your style

Answer (score 0):

basically
you have to go to the progress screen then add

```
screenOptions={{
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it through your component
go to InProgress component and change parent View backgroundColor

Comment: Only the component background changes when I do that. Rest of the page background remains the same. Please check the screenshot: prnt.sc/1qju79t But I want the entire screen color to be changed. Is there a way I can do that?